# Confirm Delivery Days in Fedex GetRate Web Service

Tags: php, web-services, soap, fedex

Does the Fedex GetRate Web Service return the delivery days (as a number) for a parcel from one location to another location as part of the web service?

Actually the reason for asking this is because I have to first fetch the delivery days what fedex returning for each types, and on top of that I need to do further date calculation as per the requirement of the shipment.

I have checked the Response of the GetRate web service but I can't find any return parameter so I am not sure if there is any other web service they are providing for this or not.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide code for what you have already tried? And it is not very clear what you are asking. What does the web service accept and return, and what are you wanting it to return?

Comment: Have you downloaded the example code? The file `RateWebServiceClient.php5` shows : `$client = new SoapClient($path_to_wsdl, array('trace' => 1)); ` and `$request['ReturnTransitAndCommit'] = true;` and `$response = $client -> getRates($request);` I think you just need to set that `ReturnTransitAndCommit` to `true` on your request parameters before sending `getRates`.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

[`/ReturnTransitAndCommit`](https://www.fedex.com/us/developer/WebHelp/ws/2017/html/WebServicesHelp/WSDVG_US_CA/wsdvg/Rate_Coding_Details.htm)

> Optional.
>
> Allows the caller to specify that the transit time and commit data are to be returned in the reply. Valid values include:
>
> - TRUE
> - FALSE

Comment: It's unclear what question this is actually answering. Single-link answers aren't great. Can you paraphrase and show how this is relevant to the problem at hand?

Answer (score 0):

Acording to [Fedex Documentation, Table 178. RateRequest Elements](https://www.fedex.com/us/developer/WebHelp/ws/2017/html/WebServicesHelp/WSDVG_US_CA/wsdvg/Rate_Coding_Details.htm)
You can get the delivery timestamp by setting to true or false the parameter **ReturnTransitAndCommit**.

```
$this->rateRequest->ReturnTransitAndCommit = true;
```

The xml request that you send, looks like:

```
<Version>
.....
</Version>
<ReturnTransitAndCommit>1</ReturnTransitAndCommit>
```

Comment: If they are using a SOAP client library, they probably won't have easy access to the XML before sending. Based on sample code provided by FedEx website, they should just have to do something like `$request['ReturnTransitAndCommit'] = true;` before sending the request via their SOAP client.